# what is difference between Hive and Cascading Lingual

Tags: hadoop, hive, cascading

Cascading provides a ANSI SQL interface(Lingual) for Apache Hadoop, lingual uses the cascading Planer to run quires.

how this Lingual is different from Hive(in what ways)?

what are advantages of lingual over hive?

Answer (score -1):

There are many efforts to bring SQL to Hadoop these days. Hive and Lingual are two but there are also Impala, Hawq, Drill, Tajo, BigSQL, Presto etc.
Each of these has some scenarios where it works best. Lingual builds on cascading so one advantage it has is that it works on other platforms and not just hadoop. Otherwise you'd need to check for yourself or describe a more specific scenario